# Internal compiler error in Eigen (v141)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, eigen

When compiling a function in the file 'ProductEvaluators.h" in the current release of Eigen using v141, I get an internal compiler error.

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
```

The function looks as follows and I narrowed down the error in / crash of the compiler to the '.sum()' in the last line:

```
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC const CoeffReturnType coeff(Index index) const
{
  const Index row = (RowsAtCompileTime == 1 || MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1) ? 0 : index;
  const Index col = (RowsAtCompileTime == 1 || MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1) ? index : 0;
  return (m_lhs.row(row).transpose().cwiseProduct( m_rhs.col(col) )).sum();
}
```

While it would of course be interesting to fix this specific error, I was also wondering, what kind of code typically provokes this kind of compiler crashes?

Comment: Does it happen without optimizations as well?  If yes, report the compiler bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Just FYI, this happens if one tries to compile Ceres, making it not usable with v141 right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen compiler crashes of MSVC on multiple occassions. Up to now, it has always been the 32-bit compiler, where the 64-bit msvc (and gcc or clang for that matter) worked fine.

Workarounds I've used is splitting expressions into smaller ones, explicitly evaluating the sub-expressions into Eigen::Matrix<> temporaries.
Keeping those temporaries in a class, and re-using those objects minimizes performance costs, but ideal it is not.